# Alerting when container goes down

Tags: docker, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, cadvisor

I've run into an issue during a setup of a monitoring stack with prometheus and cadvisor exporter. I need to receive alerts from alertmanager when container goes down unexpectedly (I mean, this could be handled by restart: unless-stopped flag?) or when container fails to start. I can see that cadvisor is expsoing a metric called container_last_seen and I can compare this with current time and alert if the value exceeds certain threshold, lets say 60 seconds.

The problem is, cadvisor exporter only holds on to the data for 5 minutes, so even if container is not running after this time, it is reported as a resolved issue, simply because this metric does not exist anymore.

This wouldn't be an issue if I had a specific container to monitor (filter by container name), but I have different containers and different projects running so I need something generic. Is there any way around this issue?

Should I perhaps add another exporter (Telegraf)?

Comment: does your containers expose metrics too or do you only haave to cadvisor metrics? In general I would not rather alert on application specific metrics than on the presence of container. A container can restart as often as it wants, as long as the SLO is not endagered

Comment: No, the containers do not expose any metrics by themselves.